# Does Bayonetta’s opening clocktower fight take a preset amount of time?

Tags: bayonetta

The opening of Bayonetta starts with a seemingly [unskippable clocktower fight](https://youtu.be/Kz2wBMdGxYo) which goes on for nearly 4 minutes. There’s no way to lose this fight, making it slow and tedious for repeat playthroughs.

Is there any way to make the opening Clocktower fight progress faster? Or does it always take a preset amount of time to complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of things, it always takes a preset amount of time. Take a look at the beginning of [this speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyLoDEXo3K4) and note that all the player does is just jump in the air and wait the cutscene out. No skips or fancy moves being used to speed up the segment.